# Problemas com DATEPICKER, usando somente mes e ano

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Boa tarde galera
Estou com um probleminha no meu plugin datepicker
Estou usando somente mês e ano nele, e ao selecionar um mês e um ano, o mês ao invés de vir em número, por exemplo 02, que quer dizer, fevereiro, ele vem em string, e em inglês ainda.
Como posso solucionar esse problema?
Segue abaixo os código:

--- NO MEU HTML ESTÁ ESSE JS: ---

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.date-picker').datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                dateFormat: 'MM yy',
                onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                                }
        });
    });
</script>
```

--- AONDE EU QUERO QUE O DATEPICKER APAREÇA ---

```
<p><label for="startDate">Data:</label></p>
            <p><input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker" type="data" name="parametro3" id="calendario" value="Ex.: 30/05/2010" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Ex.: 30/05/2010'" onFocus="if(this.value=='Ex.: 30/05/2010')this.value=''"></p>
```

--- NO MEU CSS ---

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
display: none;
}
```

Essa solução, eu encontrei aqui mesmo no fórum
Agradeço a paciência
Obrigado

Comment: Na documentação do datepicker eles devem indicar os formatos possiveis. Tente trocar MM por mm (minusculo).

Comment: Obrigado Joao, consegui resolver!!

Comment: Se possível coloque a resposta aqui para ajudar os próximos.